# Magento 2 Accessing specific page and redirect it to login account page if not login

Tags: magento-2.1

I am creating a download catalog page, I want that if the customer is not logged in and try to open that URL page they will be directed to account login page.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

use this function and redirect to login link:

```
public function isUserLoggedIn()
{
    $customerSession = $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');

    if($customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
       return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

> You need to inject Objectmanager object first.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that a redirection link or button is available somewhere in your code. You can use below code there.

```
<?php

$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$customerSession = $objectManager->get('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');

?>

<?pp if($customerSession->isLoggedIn()): ?>
    <a href="<? echo $block->getBaseUrl().'your-custom-url'; ?>">Go To Catalog Page</a>
<?php else: ?>
    <a href="<? echo $block->getBaseUrl().'customer/account/login/'; ?>">Go To Catalog Page</a>
<?php endif; ?>
```